# Python waiting for operation to complete before continuing

Tags: python, multithreading, for-loop

I'm writing data to a CSV file, then once that's done, I copy the file to another directory.

This is all in a loop, so when the second iteration starts it reads the data from the file that was copied.

The problem is that the file is still being copied while the second iteration starts and this causes obvious issues.

How would I wait for the whole function in the loop to be complete before the second iterations starts? it should be able to go on with any amount of iterations.

```
for rule in substring_rules:
    substring(rule)
```

the function:

```
        def substring(rule, remove_rows=[]):        
            writer = csv.writer(open("%s%s" % (DZINE_DIR, f), "wb"))
            from_column = rule.from_column
            to_column = rule.to_column
            reader = csv.reader(open("%s%s" % (OUTPUT_DIR, f)))
            headers = reader.next()
            index = 0
            from_column_index = None
            for head in headers:
                if head == from_column:
                    from_column_index = index
                index += 1

            if to_column not in headers:
                headers.append(to_column)

            writer.writerow(headers)

            row_index = 0
            for row in reader:
                if rule.get_rule_type_display() == "substring":
                    try:
                        string = rule.string.split(",")
                        new_value = string[0] + row[from_column_index] + string[1]
                        if from_column == to_column:
                            row[from_column_index] = new_value
                        else:
                            row.append(new_value)
                    except Exception, e:
                        print e

                if row_index not in remove_rows:
                    writer.writerow(row)
                row_index += 1
            shutil.copyfile("%s%s" % (DZINE_DIR,f), "%s%s" % (OUTPUT_DIR, f))
```

Comment: Put one loop under the other?

Comment: im not sure what your saying?  The loop is the for rule in ...:

Comment: Well python is a scripting language and runs code as a synchronous thread - it goes line by line and executes. If you need some operation to happen after another you just put it below. Currently you're trying to do everything at the same time

Comment: You don't close reader and writer

Comment: @yuvi, ok that makes sense, so in the loop, i should rather have the copy function after the substring function, not in the substring function?

Comment: Besides the fact the @jwalker is right, I'd say instead of one function that does everything, create multiple functions, each doing only some very specific task. It would also be easier to debug

Comment: You could avoid the copying by applying all the rules at once, using something like `for row in reader: for rule in substring_rules: ...`

Comment: Jup, you should close the file-access objects, and if you don't do that before you start copying, you at least need to flush. (Closing also flushes.) Otherwise, data might still be in buffers (in memory), waiting to be written until more data is coming in (which it is not, in the end).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not flushing the file for reader to disk before copying it.
(This is automatically done when the file object is garbage-collected)

instead of

```
writer = csv.writer(open("%s%s" % (DZINE_DIR, f), "wb"))
...
shutil.copyfile("%s%s" % (DZINE_DIR,f), "%s%s" % (OUTPUT_DIR, f))
```

you should write

```
wf = open("%s%s" % (DZINE_DIR, f), "wb")
writer = csv.writer(wf)
...
wf.close()
shutil.copyfile("%s%s" % (DZINE_DIR,f), "%s%s" % (OUTPUT_DIR, f))
```